# Função JQuery faz operação quando recebe data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, tenho uma função em JQuery que recebe um parâmetro data no formado Y-m-d, porém quando recebo esse dado ele faz um operação matemática de subtração e retorna o resultado. Dei uma olhada no fórum e não achei nenhuma dúvida semelhante, alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

```
function funcao(id_cliente,data) { 
   alert(data);
}
```

Exemplo: envio o valor 2018-09-18, ele trata como 1991.

Comment: Está enviando a data entre aspas? `'2018-09-18'`

Comment: como o @VictorLaio comentou, parece que está passando os valores como 2018-09-18, o que fazendo o cálculo, dá 1991, e não '2018-09-18'

Comment: Porisso perguntei se está enviando entre aspas e mesmo assim ele continua realizando os calculos, porque o @Alisson não postou um exemplo da chamada do método...